# How to use KSOAP2 with Google APIs?

Tags: android, google-api, android-ksoap2

I want to **parse Google places API using KSOAP2**. Is it possible to use **KSOAP2** in **Google APIs** i.e. Google Places API? If yes please post some examples. If no, then is there any other alternate of KSOAP2 for `Google APIs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended format for Google Places API is JSON. **KSOAP2** isn't a good library, btw.
To parse json you can use json.org library which is included in Android or something more sophisticated like Jackson.

There is a quite long tutorial how to work with Places and which library to use with it:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/